# How to make HandledMenuItem unselected when the application is started

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I have HandledMenuItem in my Application.e4xmi. But if I check this item, close my application and start it again, this item stay selected. I can suspect that this item should be tagged or something like this, but I can't find any information about tags for MenuItems.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The e4 RCP normally persists the state of the application model when the app terminates.

If you don't want to restore the persisted state of the application use the `-clearPersistedState` flag. You can also specify `-persistState false` to stop the app from persisting the state during shutdown.

If you do want to persist the application state and just clear this menu item you will have to find the `MMenuItem` item using the model service and call the `setSelected(false)` method to clear the check mark.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I was hoping that there is another way with tags, but no matter. I've noticed that in Application there is also persisted state for HandledMenuItem, but I don't know, how it works...Anyway thank you very much.

Comment: @greg-449: You are doing a great job here on SO. Are you also active in the eclipse forums? (sorry for hijacking this SO question as SO does not allow to contact users)

Comment: @erdal.karaca I look at the forums from time to time, but am not active. There are plenty of good people there.