# 3.x and E4 migration compatibility problems

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I recently migrated my eclipse 3.x rcp product to be run in e4 platform using the compatibility feature. This is distributed as a eclipse product .Everything is Woking fine except for a couple of issues

1. When the application window opens, the perspective layout partitioning lines are not showing. Whatever folders I created inside my `createinitialPerspective` Method of my perspective class doesn’t show up. my perspective class is the same in the 3.x & e4 application since I am running the compatibility feature
2. When I open the application a second time, I expect a empty window but the views from my previous use are shown. I even tried using the -clean launch option but it doesn’t clear the workspace metadata.

What can be done to solve these 2 issues?

Edit for question #1:
Product launched as a 3.x application
[image: Initial Window when launched as a 3.x app]

Product launched from eclipse oxygen with compatibility feature
[image: Initial window when launched with compatibility feature]

Comment: Please don't ask multiple separate questions in one question. It makes it difficult for people to answer. For example, here I don't understand what you mean by question 1.

Comment: @greg-449 added clarity to 1

Comment: Question 2 is probably just about using -clearPersistedState as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37388394/2670892) Question 1 you are going to have to show us your code

Comment: Thanks for the answer #2. I will try. As for #1 I will try to grab a screenshot and post it tomorrow

Comment: @greg-449 added screenshots for better illustration.